# Type inference with overloading

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, type-inference

I am working on a type system supporting overloading. I have a rough idea of how type inference is usually implemented in such a scenario, but I am wondering how - after type inference is completed - the correct implementation of an overloaded operator can be chosen. Or, in other words, how the inferred type can be passed back down the syntax tree to the operator.

For a small example, consider the expression `(x + y) + 1` where `x :: N | S, y :: a, + :: (N -> N -> N) | (S -> S -> S), 1 :: N`. `::` stands for *type of*, and `a | b` stands for type `a` *or* type `b`.

The way, I assume, type inference would now work, is to traverse the syntax tree, and for each node return a type constraint:

```
(x + y) + 1 => ((N & (N[a=N] | S[a=S])), (N & N) -> N) | ((S & (N[a=N] | S[a=S])), (S & N) -> S) => N[a=N]
  1         => N
  +         => (N -> N -> N) | (S -> S -> S)
  x + y     => ((N & (N | S)), (N & a) -> N) | ((S & (N | S)), (S & a) -> S) => N[a=N] | S[a=S]
    x       => N | S
    y       => a
    +       => (N -> N -> N) | (S -> S -> S)
```

`a & b` in this example stands for *unifying* the types `a` and `b`, `[a=T, b=U]` is a set of equality constraints for type variables.

As expected the return type of the given expression is inferred as `N[a=N]`, that is `N` where the type variable `a` is expected to be `N`.

Therefore, of the two provided implementations for the `+` operator (`N -> N -> N`, `S -> S -> S`), `N -> N -> N` should be used. In the given example, the resulting type is inferred, but not the type of the overloaded operator. My question is if there is a common pattern that is used to inform the `+` node in the syntax tree of the used implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could organize type inference as follows.

Suppose your input syntax has type `Input`. Define output syntax `Output` to be like `Input` but with explicit type annotations on all variables. The type inference would have type

```
infer : Input -> List (Output * Type)
```

That is, given some input `e`, it returns a list of possible answers. Each answer is a pair `(e', t)` where `e'` is `e` with variables annotated by types, and `t` is the inferred type of `e`.

You can view this as all happenning in the nondeterminism monad. Whenever you need to infer the type of a variable `x`, you look up its possible types `S | T | ...` and branch on each one of them. This way you do not have to "pass back" any information to sub-expressions. Instead, each sub-expressions already comes annotated, in all possible ways.

Comment: Thanks! That approach makes a lot of sense :)